# Prime number sequence?

Tags: prime-numbers

I was messing around with numbers, trying to find patterns, and came across this one:

91 isn't prime, 991 is, 9991 isn't, 99991 is...

If you keep adding 9's, does this pattern hold infinitely?

Comment: $999999991$ is not prime, it is divisible by $67$.

Comment: The terms with an odd number of 9's will always be composite, because they're equal to $10^{2n} - 9 = (10^n-3)(10^n+3)$.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha says that from $10^{11} - 9$ onwards until $10^{31}-9$ (when the exponent is odd), the numbers are all composite. However, $10^{33}-9$ (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is+10%5E33++-9++prime) is a prime, where the pattern breaks again.

Comment: Since the infinitude of Mersenne (or Fermat) primes has not been proved, I guess there is no easy proof about the existence of infinite primes of the form $10^k-9$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the pattern breaks as $999999991=67\cdot 14925373.$

In fact, your numbers $f(n)=10^n-9$ are prime exactly for $n=3, 5, 7, 33, 45, 105, 197, 199, 281, 301, 317, 1107, 1657$ when $n\le 2000.$

Comment: This is OEIS sequence [A095714](http://oeis.org/search?q=3%2C5%2C7%2C33%2C45%2C105&language=english&go=Search).

Comment: Moreover, $10^n-9$ is divisible by $67$ whenever $n \equiv 9 \mod 33$.

Comment: Similar question: does function (10^n+1)/11 except for n=3 always produce primes when n is odd?